# Count occurrences in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, reshape, crosstab

I've a Dataframe in this format:

```
| Department | Person | Power  | ... |
|------------|--------|--------|-----|
| ABC        | 1234   |  75    | ... |
| ABC        | 1235   |  25    | ... |
| DEF        | 1236   |  50    | ... |
| DEF        | 1237   | 100    | ... |
| DEF        | 1238   |  25    | ... |
| DEF        | 1239   |  50    | ... |
```

What I now want to get is the sum of occurrences for each value in the power column. How can I get this from my DataFrame?

```
| Department | 100 |  75 |  50 |  25 |
|------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| ABC        |   0 |   1 |   0 |   1 |
| DEF        |   1 |   0 |   2 |   1 |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_index.html), then generate `DataFrame` by [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and last transpose by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
print (df.Power.value_counts().sort_index(ascending=False).to_frame().T)
       100  75   50   25 
Power    1    1    2    2
```

EDIT by comment:

You need [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
print (pd.crosstab(df.Department, df.Power).sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False))
Power       100  75   50   25 
Department                    
ABC           0    1    0    1
DEF           1    0    2    1
```

Faster another solution with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
print (df.groupby(['Department','Power'])
         .size()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False))

Power       100  75   50   25 
Department                    
ABC           0    1    0    1
DEF           1    0    2    1
```

If need `groupby` by columns `Department` and `Person`, add column `Person` to `groupby` to second position (thank you [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39250504/count-occurences-in-dataframe/39250558?noredirect=1#comment65838428_39250558)):

```
print (df.groupby(['Department','Person', 'Power'])
         .size()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False))

Power              100  75   50   25 
Department Person                    
ABC        1234      0    1    0    0
           1235      0    0    0    1
DEF        1236      0    0    1    0
           1237      1    0    0    0
           1238      0    0    0    1
           1239      0    0    1    0
```

EDIT1 by comment:

If need add another missing values, use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
print (df.groupby(['Department','Power'])
         .size()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .reindex(columns=[100,75,50,25,0], fill_value=0))

Power       100  75   50   25   0  
Department                         
ABC           0    1    0    1    0
DEF           1    0    2    1    0
```

Comment: Thanks, and how can I do it, if I have a second column on which I want to group the results?

Comment: Can you add desired output, sorry, I dont understand what means `group the results`.

Comment: Thanks, I add 2 solutions. please check it.

Comment: @Gerrit for jezrael's 2nd solution with `groupby`, notice how `Power` was the second column in the `groupby` and when `unstack`ed it ended up in the columns.  If you want to have a second column on which to `groupby`, add it to the `groupby` like this: `df.groupby(['Department','Person','Power'])`.  The rest of the answer follows as above.  This is your best answer.

Comment: Thank you @piRSquared. I add it to answer.

Comment: Is it possible to get `100`, `75`, `50`, `25`, `0` in the columns independently if there are all these values in my data?

Comment: There is only `5` values or more?

Comment: I add solution, please check it.

Answer (score 1):

or it can be done this way:

```
>>> df.groupby(['Department','Power']).count().unstack().fillna(0)

           Person               
Power         25   50   75   100
Department                      
ABC           1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
DEF           1.0  2.0  0.0  1.0
```